# What is the easiest way to interpolate x, y, value timeseries to another group of points?

Tags: python, time-series, interpolation

Suppose, I have 7 timeseries, that represent a changing value measured in a point with coordinates x,y. Also I have a group of 20 points distributed spatially within the coverage of these 7 points. 
Thus I want to get 20 time series, where every value is an interpolated value of initial 7 points on a corresponding moment. Timestep is day.
I know that kriging is the best interpolation method in my case. Also I know that kriging interpolation of several points over a regular grid is easy to perform with scikit-learn or pykrige packages. But I want time series (time cycle? wouldnt it work too slowly?) and I want irregular points as target positions of interpolated values, not a regular grid.

So, what is the optimal decision here?

I've seen [this theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37123057/given-a-set-of-points-defined-in-x-y-z-coordinates-interpolate-z-value-at-a) but there is no time cycling.

On the scheme are shown: points with measured time-series (x,y,value) as o and points which are targets for interpolation as x.
[scheme of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg4Oe.jpg)

Comment: do you have to interpolate over time, too, or just over the position, but for every time step?

Comment: Just over position, only the result is to be timeseries (interpolation performed for each timestep for all points). It would be better if the method admits also a possibility of regression analisys in future(now I would like to interpolate only, by position)